# Where can I get documentation on integrating with Sage Mas 90 business object interface?

Tags: .net, integration

We need to write code to create invoices in Mas 90 4.30, and it seems that their business objects interface is what I need, but I can absolutely no documentation.  Is it available somewhere, and will it work with .NET languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Business Object Interface works with .Net.

In 4.3 and above, the File Layouts and Program Information help file is included in MAS 90 (Now Sage 100) -- Click on the Resources link on the Tasks sidebar and then look toward the bottom of the Resources page. This help file has information about each business object and data file.

To see code examples, your best option is to just start reading through the BOI forum which is very active: http://sagecity.na.sage.com/support_communities/sage100_erp/f/100.aspx

There is also an extensive video introduction to BOI Scripting (using BOI inside Sage 100 which is very similar to using it from outside Sage 100) from 90 Minds here: http://www.90minds.com/2011/06/17/business-objects-inteface-scripting-overview-video/